# Create Customized ethereum wallet

Tags: wallets

I want to create customized ethereum wallet in my web site. is there are any way to develop customized wallet ?

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by customized? You can modify open source code to make the changes you like.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , could you please suggest some open source code / projects I'm new to this and doing research about wallet.